# How to prevent android from overwriting seekbar progress when I change the orientation?

Tags: android

I have a progress bar for which I set the starting progress value in onCreate. This starting value is different in each orientation. But if I change the orientation, then android saves the old progress value and overwrites with it my new value that I gave in onCreate. How to prevent this overwrite?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Your question is unclear. You have a `SeekBar`. Your code sets the `SeekBar` to a certain value. The user then changes the `SeekBar` value by dragging the thumb. The user then rotates the screen. What value are you expecting to see in the `SeekBar`, and what value are you actually seeing in the `SeekBar`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to see in the seekbar the value that I set in onCreate, not the last value that the user set before the orientation change.

Comment: Then why are you using a `SeekBar` in the first place? If you want to show progress, and not let the user adjust it, use a `ProgressBar`.

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski: Yeah, I read that, but nothing there answers my question.

Comment: @CommonsWare I let the user adjust the seekbar, but if the orientation changes then the value set by the user must become invalid

Comment: That seems user-hostile. Orientation changes can happen accidentally. Even for intentional changes, I fail to see why the user will think that what *you* want for a `SeekBar` value is more important than what the *user* wants, and the user already told your app (in the previous orientation) what value the user wanted.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Because the value set by the user depends on the width of the screen, and the user is aware of this. So if the width changes then the value becomes invalid (a wrong value!), and the user MUST choose a new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try `android:saveEnabled="false"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:saveEnabled) on the `SeekBar` in your layout file.

Answer (score 0):

You should have e a function that "transforms" the value of the "seekbar" from one orientation to another one. You can use `onPause` and `onResume` to store and to restore the relevant value.